# Launching Gazebo simulation and using nav2 for path planning, using ros2

Tags: gazebo, ros-humble, nav2, ament, launch-file

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): cannot import name 'GazeboRosPaths' from 'scripts' 
(/home/kavinesh/Desktop/wroxai_1/test_1/install/articubot_one/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scripts/__init__.py)
```

Can somebody clarify this error?

This error started to appear when I created a `scripts` folder and added `__init__.py`, actually I am using `ament_cmake`, the ros2 launch works for other launch files but when I run a particular launch file, this error occurs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Robotics StackExchange. Please add some more context to your problem to make it clearer to others. Ideally, the structure of your package, and the launch file you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the same problem detailed in https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/1050.

The problem appeared when you created the `scripts` directory and it conflicted with the [`script` directory of `gazebo_ros_pkgs`](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/ros2/gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo_ros_paths.py#L36). Easiest workaround would be to rename your directory.